# Получение данных из MongoDB get запросом

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Помогите пожалуйста, я хочу получить данные из готовой базы. Она имеет такой вид

```
_id: ObjectId(6554d88e8513d68d49afa992)
name:Mr Evgengii Aleksandrovich Shikanov
title:Chairman of the Liquidation Commission
company:Llc Csc -Metrologia
b_phone:+7 9857628245
b_email:eshikanov@mail.ru
```

Я хочу получить всего пользователя и передать его на фронт по email(который приходит с фронта). Пока у меня есть такой код

```
//UserController
import UserModel from '../models/User.js';

export const getPerson = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body)


        const user = await UserModel.findOne(req.params. email)
        console.log(user)
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Пользователь не найден',
            });
        }
    
        res.json(user);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Ошибка сервера '
        });
    }
};
// Сама модель 
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
        },
        b_phone: {
            type: String,
        },
        b_email: {
            type: String,
        },
    }, 

);

export default mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

//index.js 
import  express  from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

import {UserController} from "./controllers/index.js"
import { userValidation } from "./validations/validations.js";


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/PersonalData')
    .then(() => 
        console.log('DB ok'))
    .catch((err) => 
        console.log('DB error',err));

        
app.get('/user', userValidation, UserController.getPerson);



app.listen(4000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }

    console.log("server ok")
})
```

Когда я делаю GET запрос по этому пути http://localhost:4000/user, то у меня в user находится null, следовательно ошибка.

Comment: может что-то типа `UserModel.findOne({ b_email: req.params.email })`?